# Is it possible to make WP7 Beta compile code with Tuples?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I use Tuples, compile breaks. Anybody knows if it possible to use Tuples within WP7 without re-implementing?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of types and methods in .NET 4 and Silverlight 4 that do not appear in WP7's framework, including Tuple. That said, Tuple shouldn't be all that hard to implement.

Comment: MarkRendle has created a sample Tuple implementation (for .net 3.5) as part of his Functional Alchemy project - http://bit.ly/functionalalchemy